# Hand and Fist gesture of gratitude

Tags: word-requests

What is the gesture called where you put a fist in a flat hand and slightly shake it to show gratitude? Here is an example: https://youtu.be/cB59VmnK52I?t=15m47s

Do you have any other examples where it is still used today?

Comment: 抱拳礼：  https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8A%B1%E6%8B%B3%E7%A4%BC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

作揖 has 3 variations. One is hold your fists, the other is touch your fists with your palm. The last one is the typical 作揖.

Nowadays, only A and B are still used.

Their usages are roughly same, for greeting, appreciation, say goodbye...

The differences are B is prefered by martial arts people, A is a gesture which anybody could use, C is a traditional gesture used by scholars.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the drawings

Answer (score 1):

拱手作揖

Don't just shake your fist at them! Bow a bit or you might get your head chopped off! Emperors can be very touchy people!